# iteration, ddply, and counts

Tags: r, loops, count, plyr

I've generated the following data frame:

```
random <- data.frame(replicate(10, sample(1:12, 564, replace=TRUE)))
```

It contains 10 columns and 564 rows. 
Each number in the column pertains to a day (1-12).
To this data frame I appended a new column containing the words "Green", "Pink" and "Red" in no particular order and filling all 564 rows using existing data I have:

```
random <- fruit$color
```

Here's what I'd like to do:

For each column 1-10, create the following table of counts:

```
Day  Green  Pink  Red
1     #     #     #
2     #     #     #
3     #     #     #
4     #     #     #
...   #     #     #
12    #     #     #
```

So, I should be able to know from this table the number of Day 1 Greens from column 1, for example. It is important that color counts from different columns are distinguishable from one another.

And there's a fun twist!

Counts for Day 9 and 10 need to be added for each Color, so each table should look like:

```
Day    Green  Pink  Red
1      #     #     #
2      #     #     #
3      #     #     #
4      #     #     #
5      #     #     #
6      #     #     #
7      #     #     #
8      #     #     #
9 - 10 #     #     #
11     #     #     #
12     #     #     #
```

So far, I've tried to work with ddply and cast to do this and loop over each column, but I'm not familiar with loops. Here's the bologna I've got so far:

```
for(i in names(random)) {
random_counts <- ddply(random, c('color', i), function(x) c(count=nrow(x)))
random_counts <- cast(random_counts, i ~ color, mean, value='count')
random_counts
}
```

Help with this would be much much appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `base` alternative:

```
# slightly smaller toy data
random <- data.frame(replicate(2, sample(1:5, 20, replace = TRUE)))
color <- sample(c("Green", "Pink", "Red"), nrow(random), replace = TRUE)

# use cut to put e.g. 3 and 4 in the same interval  
random[] <- lapply(random, function(x) cut(x, breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 4, 5)))

# count
lapply(random, function(x) table(x, color))

# $X1
#         color
# x       Green Pink Red
#   (0,1]     2    0   1
#   (1,2]     3    0   2
#   (2,4]     3    4   2
#   (4,5]     1    1   1
# 
# $X2
#         color
# x       Green Pink Red
#   (0,1]     3    0   1
#   (1,2]     4    0   1
#   (2,4]     1    3   1
#   (4,5]     1    2   3
```

Comment: No problem! In my example, I only aggregated the counts for day 3 and 4. The other bins are one day 'wide', i.e. not aggregated. Have a look at `?cut` - the right endpoints of the intervals `]` are inclusive, whereas the left endpoints `(` are not inclusive. For example, `(1,2]` includes 2, but not 1. Of course there are other ways to sum up two days, and then remove their individual lines.